# Python requests upload file with POST

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

I'm currently struggling with a really simple problem, but cant spot the problem in detail.
I want to upload a file via `requests.post`, the current approach looks kinda like:

```
    fin = open(f"{path_dtl}{filename}.dtl", "rb")
    files = {"file": fin}

    headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {auth_token}"
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"
    headers["Content-Disposition"] = f"form-data;filename ='{filename}.dtl'"

    upload_dtl = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```

The result is a `{'error': 'Invalid Media Type/Mime Type'}` response. Is there a need to open a .dtl file in different manner? The usage of a request with this configuration via Postman works fine so I guess I missed a silly mistake. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Alright... for anyone interested. The cause of the issue was the default key-value "file" in `files = {"file": fin}` is different for my API. Following workaround fixed my issue.

```
with open(f"{path_dtl}{filename}.dtl", "rb") as f: files = f.read()
...
upload_dtl = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a type? You can do so like this:

```
files = {'file': ('aaa.csv', open('aaa.csv', 'rb'),'text/csv')}
```